# How to ensure unique column value inside code?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, unique-constraint

I am learning ASP.NET MVC, and confused as to how can I ensure unique values for columns (username & email) for a table.

Can anybody help me with a sample code or a link to the tutorial which shows & explains this?

**EDIT:**

I know that I can apply an unique key constraint on my table columns and achieve it. However, I want to know how can I achieve it via ASP.NET MVC code?

**UPDATE:**

I wish to do a check in my application such that no duplicated values are passed to DAL, i.e. achieve a check before inserting a new row.

Comment: The question you're asking is related to a database, not ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @brodie: You are right, however, I wanted to know it in terms of ASP.NET MVC, so updated the question

Comment: @mliya, Have you figured out a solution for this problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

Mliya, this is something you are controlling at the database level, not at the application  level.

If you are designing a database with a `users` table in which you would like to constraint the `username` and `email` columns to be `UNIQUE` you should create a UNIQUE INDEX on such columns.

without knowing your backend database (mySQL, SQL Server, MS Access, Oracle...) it's not the case to show you pictures or tell much more, just create the table with the designer and add these unique constraints to those columns and by design you will be sure no duplicated values will ever be inserted for username and email.

I also suggest you to create an ID column which would be set as PK (primary key, which means it will be automatically set as NON NULL and UNIQUE).

From your ASP.NET MVC application you should of course make sure that no duplicated values are then passed to the DAL for username and email. You could do this in different ways, the easiest is probably to check before inserting a new row if any user already exists with that username and/or email and if so you can show a notification message telling the user to please select another pair of values.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wish to do, check in my application that no duplicated values are passed to DAL, i.e. achieve a check before inserting a new row. Can you help me in this regards? Thanks in advance!

Comment: show us how you are doing the insert right now and let's see how we can add a check ;-)

Comment: Can you suggest some generic sample code which demonstrates such a functionality?

Comment: If you check prior to the insert you still have a chance of 2 identical usernames hitting the database. The window is small I admit, but could happen and would be more likely if the application gets busy and is distributed across multiple servers. So I think the database error also needs to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

In an ASP.NET MVC architecture, you should try to do most of your validation in the Model, but with low-level validation rules like these, it's sometimes impossible. What you should look to for answers then is Domain-driven Design (DDD) where [Application Services](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design/) can solve such low-level needs.

Application Services will have access to the database (either directly, or better yet; indirectly through [repositories](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/03/ddd-repository-implementation-patterns/)) and can perform low-level validation and throw `ValidationException` or something similar (with detailed information the `Controller` can act upon and respond to the user) when a prerequisite or business rule isn't met.

[S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) implementes all of this in a best-practice framework that you can use as a basis for your ASP.NET MVC applications. It is highly opinionated towards DDD principles and NHibernate, and it will sometimes force your hand on how you do stuff, which is kind of the point. The most important part about it is that it learns you how to deal with these kinds of problems.

To answer your question more concretely and in the spirit of DDD, this is how I would solve it:

```
public class UserController
{
    private readonly IUserService userService;

    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        // The IUserService will be injected into the controller with
        // an "Inversion of Control" container like NInject, Castle Windsor
        // or StructureMap:
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public ActionResult Save(UserFormModel userFormModel)
    {
        if (userFormModel.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // Mapping can be performed by AutoMapper or some similar library
                UserDto userDto = Mapper.Map<UserDto>(userFormModel);
                this.userService.Save(userDto);
            }
            catch (ValidationException ve)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = ve.Detail;
            }
        }

        // Show validation errors or redirect to a "user saved" page.
    }
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        // The IUserRepository will be injected into the service with
        // an "Inversion of Control" container like NInject, Castle Windsor
        // or StructureMap:
        this.userRepository = userReposityr;
    }

    public UserDto Save(UserDto userDto)
    {
        using (this.userRepository.BeginTransaction())
        {
            if (!this.userRepository.IsUnique(userDto.UserName))
            {
                // The UserNameNotUniqueValidationException will inherit from ValidationException
                // and build a Detail object that contains information that can be presented to
                // a user.
                throw new UserNameNotUniqueValidationException(userDto.UserName);
            }

            userDto = this.userRepository.Save(userDto);
            this.userRepository.CommitTransaction();

            return userDto;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, since I am learning asp.net mvc, I am not too sure as to whether this answer is really basics or it includes (some) advanced feature. Can you please comment on this

Comment: My answer is an attempt to teach a "best practice" implementation of an n-tier ASP.NET MVC application. It's mostly relevant if you want to build very large-scale applications, but once you have all the plumbing for IoC and such in place, it's not much more difficult than a more basic implementation. If you want your application to grow, this is the way to do it.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this solution is performing a test against the database before the save, and it would still be theoretically possible for 2 users to be entering the data at exactly the same time, both pass the IsUnique test but then one will fail the database unique constraint. I guess a try/catch around the save which translates the DB error into a user error would handle that?

Comment: @DaleBurrell, You are correct, but I think atomicity is better achieved through the use of transactions, so I added a transaction scope around the unique/save operations that will handle race conditions like the one you describe.